# Why does the link's drop out from the nav bar when adding if & else statement's?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYzlR.png)

[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpXCp.png)

Here's screenshots from my problem for better understanding.

Comment: Don't paste images of the code. Paste the original code here please.

Answer (score 0):

Make `if user_signed_in?` and its corresponding `else` 1 more level nested. That will fix the issue.

And don't forget to move inner content e.g. `link_to` also by 1 level of nesting.